# Encoding order relations in CNF

Tags: np-complete, encoding-scheme, normal-forms

I want convert timetable scheduling problems to SAT problems. Suppose there are $t$ time slots and $c$ classes. I will define $t\times c$ variables $x_{ij}$, which is true iff class $j$ takes place in time slot $i$. My problem is: suppose there is a constraint that class $a$ takes place after class $b$. How to encode that efficiently in CNF?

Answer (score 1):

Variable $a_i$ set means class $a$ is in timeslot $i$, with a similar encoding for class $b$.  Higher values of $i$ means later time slots.  If class $a$ must occur before class b then you need clauses to declare that exactly one of $a_i$ or $b_{i+1}$, $b_{i+2}$ ... is set.  You need one such declaration for each $a_i$ possibility.  E.g.

ExactlyOne($a_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, ...$)

ExactlyOne($a_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, ...$)

ExactlyOne($a_3, b_4, b_5, b_6, ...$)

which is efficiently encoded using *commander variable encoding* as described in [Efficient CNF Encoding for Selecting 1 to N Objects](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wklieber/papers/2007_efficient-cnf-encoding-for-selecting-1.pdf).  The scheme requires $O(n)$ clause growth, unlike the naive encoding method which requires $O(n^2)$ clause growth.

Comment: Sorry I don’t follow your reasoning. Suppose $a_1$ and $b_2$ are true, then none of the ExactlyOne clauses will be true. What are you trying to specify here?

Comment: I'd misremembered something I worked on earlier.  I've replaced my broken encoding with a link to an efficient coding scheme.

Comment: I think it should be $(a_1 \land (b_2 \lor b_3 \lor \cdots)) \lor (a_2 \land (b_3 \lor b_4 \lor \cdots)) \lor \cdots$. But will turning this to CNF result in an efficient encoding? I’m too lazy to work.

Comment: Yes, CNF clause growth is quadratic as the number of ordering restrictions and time slots increase.  The paper I linked to offers a method with better asymptotic clause growth.